# windows form coordinates as geopoint(longitude, latitude)

Tags: c#, sql-server, spatial

I would like to insert row into `database` on the click on `Windows Form`, as `geography` point (using `SQL Server`) and then draw image on the place where user click. I am getting `x` and `y` coordinates from `MousePosition.X`, however when I insert those values into database like:

```
            string connetionString = null;

            connetionString = "Data Source=DEVEL-MACHINE\\DEVELOPINSTANCE;Initial Catalog=spdb;Integrated Security=True" ;
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                String query = "INSERT INTO vertex VALUES( geography::Parse('POINT(" + MousePosition.X.ToString() + " " + MousePosition.Y.ToString() + ")'),'" + nameBox.Text + "')";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statuslbl.Text = "Status połączenia: BRAK";
                statuslbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
                statuslbl.Visible = true;
            }
```

I get error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A .NET Framework error occurred during
>   execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":

my query look `"INSERT INTO vertex VALUES( geography::Parse('POINT(600 379)'),'test')"`

is there any way to treat Form coordinates as `geopoint` in a way to revert the operation? I mean in a Way to store coordinates like that as `geopoint` and later after get `select` on a table draw an image in the `600 379` point?